# My Arduino is heating up

Tags: motor, heat, servo

I am working on a simple Arduino project where I am controlling 5 TowerPro servos. I read that each takes up 2.2 V each so that means the Arduino can only handle about 2 , if using 5V. So far Ive connected 4 with no issues but when I added the 5th the whole thing stopped and the 5V regulator was really hot. That means I don't have enough power and the Arduino is just having a hard time giving not enought volts for all five servos. I just don't know what to do now. Ive tried adding 3  3V battery packs instead of the Arduino but it was smoking. Is there another way to provide the right amount of power for 5 servos without breaking or burning anything!

Comment: You need to determine how much *current* is required too, it's not just the voltage that matters. Can you show a schematic of how things are currently connected?

Comment: I suggest going back to read the basics about voltage and current, especially the part about parallel circuits. You seem to be confused about quite a few things. That said, without any sort of data about the servos or the circuit connections I doubt anybody will give an answer that you're happy with

Comment: Don't power the servos from the Arduino.  Power them separately, and only connect the ground and control signal lines to the Arduino.

Comment: `I read that each takes up 2.2 V each so that means the Arduino can only handle about 2 , if using 5V` - that doesn't mean you can power two 2.2V servos from 5V. It doesn't work that way. Can you edit your question and include a link to the servos and preferably the datasheet?

Answer (score 2):

The voltage regulator on the Arduino is designed to power the logic circuits, and perhaps a few LEDs and other digital devices. It is not designed to power 5 motors.

You haven't specified what *current* they draw - that is the important question, not the voltage.

As the comments under your question have said, you need to power the motors separately from the Arduino, not *through* it. However, connect the *ground wires*, and use the Arduino to control the signal wire to the servos.

The graphic below shows the general idea. For 5 servos even those batteries are probably not enough.

Notice that the power for the motor does not go through the Arduino.

[image: Powering a servo]